# Messages shows inactive iCloud account

Tags: macos, messages

On Yosemite Messages my iCloud account is shown as inactive although I use it constantly for Mail, Notes, Contacts etc. It is also slow to log in when I enter my password and sometimes that fails.

How do I make it active? I do have a serial number for my Mac so the most obvious issue is probably not there.

It seemed to work up to when I chnaged my iPhone to a new 6S I has all the SMS messages from my old phone